# System-Level Network Security (Packet Classification and etc.) - SELinux and Libnftnl

Tags: linux, rhel, security, iptables, selinux

I asked the same question in the [Security forum](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/145844/network-security-on-linux-libnftnl-vs-selinux), but since no respond did I get, I'm posting it here either.

---

I read that Libnftnl is a userspace library providing a low-level netlink programming interface to the in-kernel nf_tables subsystem and it uses NFTables.

*[UPDATE] : NFTables is used for in-kernel packet classification.*

Since it's a kernel related topic, at the very first time of hearing it the only thing sprang to my mind was SELinux whilst we can use it to manage our networking security solutions such as Labeled Networking (Labeling Packets passing between machines over the Network) amongst all other options it provides.

So is it something like what we can do via SELinux or not? If not so, does anyone know why we may be in need of using NFTables and Libnftnl? Do we need it at all?

Comment: SELinux was security for linux system and server applications like apache,squid,etc.SELinux was not Network security. Was NFtables related with IPTables? Iptables was linux firewall. SELinux was not Linux Firewall.

Comment: Intrusion Detection System (IDS) was network security.SELinux didnt protect linux network.

Comment: @supriady Yes NFTables is related to IPTables. I know SELinux is not a network security solution and we should use IDSs and etc. But we have options to do with SELinux - at least for system-level protection - for instance we have something called Labeled Networking, you can read more [here](http://selinuxproject.org/page/NB_Networking). I thought libnftnl might be using something similar.

Comment: @supriady I updated my title to a more convenient one.

Comment: The link mentioned SELinux networking support for iptables,ipsec,etc.Many server applications like apache,openvpn with ipsec,squid,etc are related with SElinux Networking Support.SELinux cant protect server applications without networking support.Actually what did you want to do with SElinux and NFtables?And you posted it here.

Comment: @supriady I want to see what options do I have for packet classification? I want to - should - set rules for every little thing possible from directory and files to executable commands, daemons, ports, packets, and so on. At the moment I've got confused about the options I may have for setting rules on incoming and outgoing packets. On the other hand, I'm not sure if any of these will help me through the QoS or not, and if there is a way to prioritize packets.